# SVG animation in Processing not drawing at correct location

Tags: animation, svg, processing

I'm trying to make a simple, quick and dirty demo interface in Processing, with the widget animations being made up of SVG frames that I loop through. I'm just learning and I don't really have any experience in this area, so bear with me. 
The problem is that the x,y coordinates I have entered are not where the SVG is drawing.
[Here is a screenshot comparing expected draw location vs actual draw location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLhUR.png)

I've checked my original SVGs (created in Adobe Animate CC and exported frame by frame), I played with shapeMode(), I tried to translate with path coordinates from the viewBox (it didn't change anything), and I've spent way too much time searching online.  Here is the code:

```
ArrayList<Button> buttons;

//creating background grid(50x50)
int nbOfHorizontalLines = 20;
int nbOfVerticalLines = 30;

void setup() {
  size(1500, 1000);
  buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

  // button constructor: x, y, width, height, text
  buttons.add(new Button (100, 100, 100, 100, "100,100 (top left corner of button should be drawn here)"));

}

void draw() {
  background(200);
  frameRate(20);

  float distanceBetweenHorizontalLines = (float)height/nbOfHorizontalLines;
  float distanceBetweenVerticalLines = (float)width/nbOfVerticalLines;

  for(int i = 0; i < nbOfHorizontalLines; i++)
  {
    stroke(#56A9FA);
    line(0, i *distanceBetweenHorizontalLines, width, i*distanceBetweenHorizontalLines);  
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < nbOfVerticalLines; i++)
  {
    stroke(#56A9FA);
    line(i*distanceBetweenVerticalLines, 0, i*distanceBetweenVerticalLines, height);
  }

  // draw buttons
  for (Button b : buttons) {
    b.drawButton();

  }
  textSize(15);
  text("~210,140", 210, 128);
}
```

Here is the class for the Button (edited for the sake of this post so that it only draws one frame, instead of looping through all my SVG files) :

```
class Button {

  float x, y;
  //width and height
  float w, h;
  //cycles through the animation files 
  ArrayList<PShape> restFrames;
  //var to load current frame
  PShape frame;
  int frameIndex;
  //assign text string from parameter to t
  String t;


  public Button(float newX, float newY, float newWidth, float newHeight, String newText) {

    x = newX;
    y = newY; 
    w = newWidth ;
    h = newHeight;
    frameIndex = 0;
    t = newText;
    restFrames = new ArrayList<PShape>();

    restFrames.add(loadShape("cleanBreathingNoBG_1.svg"));

  }

  void drawButton() {
    shapeMode(CORNER);
    PShape frame = restFrames.get(frameIndex);

    shape(frame, x, y, w, h);  
    textSize(18);
    fill(0);
    textAlign(LEFT, TOP);
    text(t, x, y);
  }
}
```

And finally, the code for the SVG itself:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0px" y="0px" width="386px" height="363px" viewBox="0 0 386 363">
<defs>
<path id="Layer0_0_1_STROKES" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5.2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
M 454.95 160.95
Q 478.0671875 309.616015625 464.95 476.9"/>

<path id="Layer0_1_1_STROKES" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5.2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
M 464.95 476.9
Q 607.547265625 499.9689453125 769.9 479.9"/>

<path id="Layer0_2_1_STROKES" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5.2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
M 770.9 481.9
Q 761.9529296875 312.828515625 769.9 158.95"/>

<path id="Layer0_3_1_STROKES" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5.2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
M 454.95 157.95
Q 614.925 174.6916015625 769.9 156.95"/>

<path id="Layer0_4_1_STROKES" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5.2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
M 463.95 475.9
L 442.95 502.9"/>

<path id="Layer0_5_1_STROKES" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5.2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
M 769.9 478.9
L 783.9 503.9"/>

<path id="Layer0_6_1_STROKES" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5.2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
M 771.9 158.95
L 782.9 183.95"/>

<path id="Layer0_7_1_STROKES" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5.2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
M 785.9 505.9
Q 781.89296875 341.61796875 784.9 187.95"/>

<path id="Layer0_8_1_STROKES" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5.2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
M 446.95 504.9
Q 616.425 506.6560546875 780.9 505.9"/>

<path id="Layer0_9_1_STROKES" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5.2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
M 452.95 159.95
L 439.95 182.95"/>

<path id="Layer0_10_1_STROKES" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5.2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
M 442.95 501.9
Q 449.8580078125 337.425 439.95 186.95"/>
</defs>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, -421,-144.75) ">
<use xlink:href="#Layer0_0_1_STROKES"/>
</g>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, -421,-144.75) ">
<use xlink:href="#Layer0_1_1_STROKES"/>
</g>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, -421,-144.75) ">
<use xlink:href="#Layer0_2_1_STROKES"/>
</g>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, -421,-144.75) ">
<use xlink:href="#Layer0_3_1_STROKES"/>
</g>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, -421,-144.75) ">
<use xlink:href="#Layer0_4_1_STROKES"/>
</g>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, -421,-144.75) ">
<use xlink:href="#Layer0_5_1_STROKES"/>
</g>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, -421,-144.75) ">
<use xlink:href="#Layer0_6_1_STROKES"/>
</g>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, -421.7,-148.75) ">
<use xlink:href="#Layer0_7_1_STROKES"/>
</g>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, -421,-144.75) ">
<use xlink:href="#Layer0_8_1_STROKES"/>
</g>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, -421,-144.75) ">
<use xlink:href="#Layer0_9_1_STROKES"/>
</g>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, -421,-144.75) ">
<use xlink:href="#Layer0_10_1_STROKES"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

If additional information is needed, please let me know if I've missed anything! I appreciate the help, as I'm a bit of a beginner and no one around me knows much about this either.

Comment: Can you narrow your problem down to only using a single `svg` file instead of looping through 51 separate files? I'd like to help, but I need to be able to copy and paste your code to run it on my machine. (In other words, try to post a [mcve].)

Comment: Thank you @KevinWorkman, I've edited it to only draw the one SVG.  Hopefully that should do it!

Answer (score 0):

The offset is coming from inside your `svg` file.

I tested this by loading your `svg` file alongside another `svg` file (which I got from going to `File > Examples > Basics > Shape > LoadDisplaySVG` and then going to `Sketch > Show Sketch Folder` and then copying `bot1.svg` from the example's `data` directory into my `data` directory. Then I run this code:

```
PShape yourShape;
PShape myShape;

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
  yourShape = loadShape("image.svg");
  myShape = loadShape("bot1.svg");
}

void draw(){
  background(200);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
  shape(yourShape, mouseX, mouseY, 100, 100);
  shape(myShape, mouseX, mouseY, 100, 100);
}
```

The `image.svg` file is your `svg` file, and this is what I see:

[image: svg offsets]

This shows that "my" `svg` file draws with `mouseX, mouseY` as its upper-left corner, but yours has the offset.

Now, I'm not sure **why** your `svg` contains the offset, but this at least shows you that it's not the Processing code, and provides you with a simpler example that you can play with. If I were you I would go through your `svg` file with a fine-toothed comb. The offset might be obvious to somebody else, but I'm not very familiar with `svg` files. Good luck.